# How do I keep my Amazon Linux EC2 instance /var/log/messages from being filled with dhclient and ec2net messages?

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, logging

On Amazon Linux in AWS's EC2 service, it uses a very short DHCP lease time, meaning that `/var/log/messages` gets lines in it every couple of minutes from the `dhclient` and `ec2net` services. How can I exclude those from logging, so any important log messages don't get lost in the noise (and while it's not that much disk space, it just seems like a waste, and extra logging to Cloudwatch Logs that I don't really need). Presumably, if I end up running into trouble with it getting an IP address, I can turn the logging back on (if I can get back onto the box at all).

These kinds of messages are the ones being repeated every couple of minutes:

```
Jun  8 09:14:49 server-name dhclient[2206]: PRC: Renewing lease on eth0.
Jun  8 09:14:49 server-name dhclient[2206]: XMT: Renew on eth0, interval 9900ms.
Jun  8 09:14:49 server-name dhclient[2206]: RCV: Reply message on eth0 from fe80::my:link:locl:addr.
Jun  8 09:14:49 server-name ec2net: [get_meta] Trying to get http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/0a:91:b3:my:mac:addr/local-ipv4s
Jun  8 09:14:49 server-name ec2net: [rewrite_aliases] Rewriting aliases of eth0
Jun  8 09:14:49 server-name ec2net: [get_meta] Trying to get http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/0a:91:b3:my:mac:addr/subnet-ipv4-cidr-block
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This just involves telling the logging system to ignore messages from `dhclient` and `ec2net`. Edit the `/etc/rsyslog.conf` file, and after the `#### RULES ####` line and before the lines defining logging for the other files, add these two lines:

```
:programname,isequal,"dhclient"  ~
:programname,isequal,"ec2net"    ~
```

The `~` indicates "don't log this" per the `rsyslog.conf` man page.

Then, run `service rsyslog restart` to have the system restart the logging daemon.

---

For **Amazon Linux 2**, rsyslogd has been updated to support the somewhat more intuitive "stop" keyword, so you can use these lines instead:

```
:programname,isequal,"dhclient"  stop
:programname,isequal,"ec2net"    stop
```

And restart the service with `systemctl restart rsyslog`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I thought it might be because the program name seems to include the pid.  Eg. it is 'dhclient[2206]' rather than just 'dhclient'.  However, using startswith instead of isequal didn't work for me either.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either on 'Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)'. rsyslogd version is 8.24.0-52.amzn2.

Comment: It worked for me on a current version of Amazon Linux 2 of June 2022. I only added `:programname,isequal,"dhclient" stop` and restarted the service as described above.